# How to use justify-between Tailwind?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm new to tailwind css. I have a navbar that I'm trying to add a container and `justify-between` but the CSS is not applying. Meaning, it's not adding the spacing. But `justify-around` does work, and the background color works as well, which is interesting Tailwind is installed correctly Here is my code...

```
const NavBar = () => {
    return (
        <header className="bg-red-600">
            <div className="container mx-auto flex justify-between">
                <nav>
                    <NavLink to="/" exact>
                        Shloimi
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="/post">
                        Blog Posts
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="/project">
                        Projects
                    </NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="/about">
                        About
                    </NavLink>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
    );
};

function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <NavBar/>
            <Switch>
                <Route component={Home} path='/' exact/>
                <Route component={About} path='/about'/>
                <Route component={SinglePost} path='/post/:slug'/>
                <Route component={Post} path='/post'/>
                <Route component={Project} path='/project'/>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Because, `justify-between` utilities for controlling how flex and grid items are positioned along a container's main axis.
So you need change like this.. `justify-between` working as parents if two and more childrens. in the case `NavLink` is childrens

```
        <nav className="container mx-auto flex justify-between">
                <NavLink to="/" exact>
                    Shloimi
                </NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/post">
                    Blog Posts
                </NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/project">
                    Projects
                </NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/about">
                    About
                </NavLink>
        </nav>
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Thats' not what I'm referring to.  The actual `container mx-auto` is not working, meaning it's not giving it spacing from the left

Comment: because, you didn't define `width`, I recommend `w-full` to fix it. or check the `.container` or `header` tag's css define in your using css file like `index.css` or `App.css`. :)

Comment: you can check, https://play.tailwindcss.com/6VUmwzD8yK , if your code didn't work, then please check your css file or config file,  let me know it's not working by comment with a revised share link here. :)